Extract a table from a webpage using rvest
I am trying to extract a table found at the bottom of this page.
I have loaded the rvest library and attempted several functions to try to get the table. Namely using the xpath of the table which I copied after right-clicking on the page and inspecting the element and copying the XPath.
webpage <- webpage <- read_html("https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KBNA/date/2024-9-30")
Copy XPath:
webpage %>% html_element(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/app-history/one-column-layout/wu-header/sidenav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table")
Copy Full XPath:
webpage %>% html_element(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/app-history/one-column-layout/wu-header/sidenav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table")
When copying just the XPath, I receive the following error:
Error: unexpected symbol in "webpage %>% html_element(xpath = "//*[@id="inner"
When copying the full XPath, I get:
{xml_missing} <NA>
How do I extract the table using the XPath? Or is there another method with rvest?

So there are a few things you are running into. First the website uses javascript to build the HTML's so you are going to need to use read_html_live to trigger this process. Second If you look at the xpath you will notice that they have "" in them. This is fine as long as you account for that in the xpath argument. In your case you use "xpath = "//*[@id="inner" which will through the unexpected symbol because R thinks that the " in the xpath is closing the " at the beggining. The most straightforward solution is to use ' instead
library(rvest)
  
## this is just for reprex's purpose
  
session = read_html_live('https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/KBNA/date/2024-9-30')

dat = session |>
  html_element(xpath = '//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table') |>
  html_table()

head(dat)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   Time  Temperature `Dew Point` Humidity Wind  `Wind Speed` `Wind Gust` Pressure
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <chr>        <chr>       <chr>   
#> 1 12:3… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    WNW   5 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> 2 12:5… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    W     3 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> 3 1:53… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    WNW   5 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> 4 2:53… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    WNW   3 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> 5 3:53… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    CALM  0 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> 6 4:53… 67 °F       64 °F       90 °%    WSW   3 °mph       0 °mph      29.25 °…
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: Precip. <chr>, Condition <chr>

Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

I got the following error: Error in new_chromote && !self$session$is_active() :
invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Do you have a copy of google chrome installed as documented https://rvest.tidyverse.org/reference/read_html_live.html

The link doesn't work

just edited the comment

Yes, but I keep getting the same error

it finally worked after countless attempts, I can't pinpoint the reason why though.
